# ROS/Hydro installation error:qt_dotgraph: No definition of [python-pygraphviz] for OS

Tags: ros, rosdep-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I tried to install ROS/Hydro in OS X10.9 with homebrew following with ：http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source

When I run `$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y`, I got

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:

qt_dotgraph: No definition of [python-pygraphviz] for OS [osx]
```

qt-4.8.6 and graphviz-2.38.0 are already installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208517/ros/hydro-installation-error:qt_dotgraph:-no-definition-of-%5Bpython-pygraphviz%5D-for-os/) by [Whitesail](https://answers.ros.org/users/22342/whitesail/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BobPeret](https://answers.ros.org/users/22357/bobperet/) on 2015-05-05**:
I am experiencing the same error.  I am installing on OS X Yosemite following the directions at "http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source"

**Comment by [Whitesail](https://answers.ros.org/users/22342/whitesail/) on 2015-05-05**:
I still can not solve this problem. How about you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, I fixed it by

`$ rosdep install -s --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y --skip-keys "python-pygraphviz"`

referenced from [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/153156/rosdep-error-while-i-try-to-install-ros-on-os-x-108/?answer=153276#post-id-153276)

I don't know whether there will be further problems by doing this. But it works now.

---

Originally posted by [Whitesail](https://answers.ros.org/users/22342/whitesail/) with karma: 16 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0